# Minimum Tension Force Resistance, Chain Links

Tags: forces

Say we have a chain made up with 10 metal links.

By pulling on both ends' links in opposite directions, we apply tension force of, say 100 N.

For the chain to remain unbroken under this tension, does each link need to be at least...

10 N tension resistant?
Or 100 N?
Other?

Why?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If the chain was resting on a flat surface then the tension in each link would be 100 N.  If the chin was hanging then the top link would have the weight of the rest of the chain and the 100 N force to contend with.  The reason is that each link has to have a net force of zero on it otherwise they would accelerate.  So if you apply 100N to one link the next link will have to apply 100 N on the first link.  Newton's third law tells you that the first link exerts a force of 100 N on the second link.  To have a net force of zero on the second link the third link . . . . . etc